# ¿Cómo convertir una fecha devuelta por un JSON desde una base de datos MongoDB?

Tags: java, json, mongodb, selenium

Estoy consumiendo un servicio de una base de datos en **MongoDB**, el JSON que me devuelve contiene varios datos que necesito, pero uno de ellos es la fecha de nacimiento, pero sucede que me devuelve este valor:

```
"fechaNacimiento": {
    "$date": 218937600000
  }
```

Ese `$date` no entiendo como lo convierto en una fecha real en Java, porque podría intentar con esta instrucción:

```
Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();  
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");  
String strDate = dateFormat.format(date);
```

Pero lo que me haría seria convertir `218937600000` en un string, pero sigue sin ser una fecha real, agradecería su ayuda para solucionar eso.

Alguna serialización en Java, de MongoDB (JSON) a una fecha real en Java.

Comment: Hola: Que fecha deberia ser 218937600000

Comment: 1976-12-08  esta seria la fecha devuelta por 218937600000

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Al parecer las fechas que estás recibiendo en tu consulta están expresadas en milisegundos, usando lo que se conoce como [*Tiempo Unix*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_Unix).

**JAVA 8**

Para obtener el valor de la fecha almacenada usando dicho formato, debes realizar una conversión de milisegundos a un objeto [*LocalDate*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) (para el caso en que sólo quieras la fecha) o a un objeto [*LocalDateTime*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) (para el caso que además se incluya hora, minutos y segundos).

Hacer esta conversión es sencillo, ya que dispones de la Clase [Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html)

En primer lugar debemos almacenar el valor recibido en tu consulta, el mismo lo vamos declarar como [*Long*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html), ya que los valores enteros en milisegundos son lo suficientemente grandes como para quedar fuera de rango de un tipo [*Integer*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html).

Luego usaremos el método [`ofEpochMilli()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochMilli-long-), que recibe como argumento precisamente un tipo `Long`.

También usaremos el método [`atZone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#atZone-java.time.ZoneId-) para crear un objeto [*ZonedDateTime*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) con la zona horaria a la que queramos convertir nuestro valor en milisegundos.

Por último usaremos el método [*toLocalDate*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#toLocalDate--) o [*toLocalDateTime*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#toLocalDateTime--) para convertir finalmente el valor de milisegundos en un objeto `LocalDate` o `LocalDateTime`, con el cual podremos trabajar luego en nuestro código.

Una implementación básica sería la siguiente:

```java
// obtienes el valor de milisegundos de tu consulta (aquí lo uso directamente)
long milliseconds = 218937600000L;
// Usamos el ZoneID del sistema y usaremos la clase LocalDate
LocalDate localDate = Instant.ofEpochMilli(milliseconds).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
// Usamos el ZOneID UTC si deseamos la fecha en UTC
LocalDate utcDate = Instant.ofEpochMilli(milliseconds).atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toLocalDate();
//Mostramos el resultado
System.out.println("milliseconds: " + milliseconds);
System.out.println("Local Date: " + localDate);
System.out.println("UTC Date: " + utcDate);
```

Con esto ya tienes una forma de trabajar con los milisegundos que obtienes de la Base de Datos. (Siempre que los mismos correspondan al formato de Tiempo Unix o POSIX)

Una implementación en consola de esto podría verse así:

```java
import java.time.*;

public class millisecondsToLocalDateTime {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long milliseconds = 218937600000L;
    LocalDate localDate = Instant.ofEpochMilli(milliseconds).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
    LocalDate utcDate = Instant.ofEpochMilli(milliseconds).atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toLocalDate();
    System.out.println("milliseconds: " + milliseconds);
    System.out.println("Local Date: " + localDate);
    System.out.println("UTC Date: " + utcDate);
  }
}
```

La cual produce la siguiente salida:

[image: Salida del código Java]

Se observa que la fecha en cuestión es 09 de Diciembre de 1976 (por coincidencia mi año de nacimiento).

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Answer (score 3):

> Podes usar Calendar, este tiene un método que es para setearlo con mili segundos
>   Lo único que el mes arranca desde 0 así que hay que sumarle 1.

```
   Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
   calendar.setTimeInMillis(218937600000L);

   System.out.println("Dia: "+calendar.get(calendar.DATE));
   System.out.println("Mes: "+(1+calendar.get(calendar.MONTH)));
   System.out.println("Año: "+calendar.get(calendar.YEAR));
```

Comment: es una excelente manera para evitar volver un vector el String que devuelve el LocalDate

Answer (score 0):

me funciono perfectamente, de pronto a diferencia de tu código cambie a ofEpochMilli, pero por el resto esta muy bien, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;

import static java.time.Instant.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long milliseconds = 218937600000L;
        LocalDate localDate = ofEpochMilli(milliseconds).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
        LocalDate utcDate = ofEpochMilli(milliseconds).atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toLocalDate();
        System.out.println("milliseconds: " + milliseconds);
        System.out.println("Local Date: " + localDate);
        System.out.println("UTC Date: " + utcDate);
    }
}
```